# TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined in Jest test using ReactDOM

Tags: webpack, jestjs

I'm trying to add Jest support for testing code in my webpack based application.  I think I have the basic configuration right, as a non-component based test (like 'adds numbers' below) passes.  However, when I try to interact with the DOM, an error results.  I'm trying a variation of the smoketest scenario described in the [create-react-apps docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests) docs (Test components section).  My test file look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

it('adds number', () => {
  expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);
});

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<div/>, div);
});
```

and the output is:

> v adds number (10ms)
>
> × renders without crashing (3ms)
>
> renders without crashing
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
>
> ```
>  44 | it('renders without crashing', () => {
>  45 |   const div = document.createElement('div');
>  46 |   ReactDOM.render(<div/>, div);
>     |            ^
>  47 | });
> ```

```
  at Object.<anonymous> (/pathto/TestFile.test.tsx:46:12)
```

My application is not built with create-react-app. Instead I tried to follow the instructions in [Jest webpack documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack), modifying it in support of Typescript.  Should I expect the sample 'renders without crashing' to work in my application?  Do I need to set any browser Jest configuration to support this?  This is the main configuration in my package.json related to Jest:

```
"jest": {
  "roots": [
    "src/app/react"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
    ".+\\.(scss)$": "./node_modules/jest-css-modules-transform"
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "ts",
    "tsx"
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this to your `tsconfig.json`:

```ts
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  ...
}
```

---

**Details**

The issue stems from how this line is transpiled:

```ts
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

That line means import the `default` export from the `react-dom` module as `ReactDOM`.

`react-dom` ships as a CommonJS module so technically it doesn't have a `default` export.

Setting the `esModuleInterop` flag to `true` lets you import its single exported value as if it was the `default` export of a TypeScript or ES6 module.

Comment: Thanks so much! Good explanation :)

Comment: After knocking my head on my desk for a while, I finally saw your answer and fixed it. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add `esModuleInterop` config for some reason, the correct syntax to import a module in TypeScript as a single name is:

```ts
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```